# Why am i getting "No overload method for Add takes 1 argument" when adding a Dictionary to a List of Dictionaries

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is basic.  I am a little new to C#, but why cant I add a Dictionary to the list of Dictionaries? The documentation I have looked up does it like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { "test", "" });
```

Comment: This will be a lot less awful in the next version of C# which will allow `new Dictionary<string, string> { ["test"] = "" }`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you create your `Dictionary<string, string>` in the second line, you are not initializing it correctly.

What you need is this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"test", ""} });
```

This creates a new key/value pair and adds it to the Dictionary. The compiler though you were trying to add an element called "test" and one called "" to the dictionary; which you can't do because those add operations require a value as well as a key.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, very sorry for the very simple question

Comment: @IvanRistic No problem, I had to think about it for a while before I realized the braces were missing. Good question!

Answer (score 5):

You are using the collection initializer for a list or array. A dictionary has keys and values, so it needs to have a set of parameters in braces:

```
data.Add(
    new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    { 
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
        { "key3", "value3" } 
    }
);
```

[Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Add extra `{}`

```
data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"test", ""} });
```

Without extra brackets, you are trying to add two individual strings, `"test"` and `""`, while you want to add a key-value pair.

Answer (score 2):

OK.  The "List of Dictionaries" is probably over complicating the issue.
You get the same error just with this line:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>() { "test", "" };
```

The issue is populating a dictionary in this manner.
If my example was changed to:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
x.Add("test", "");
```

then going back to your original example, this will work:

```
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        var x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        x.Add("test", "" );
        data.Add(x);
```

BTW, why would you require a list of dictionaries.  Sounds quite a compilcated design pattern to use - although technically valid.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary object is expecting key and value, while you are only passing the key. When initializing a dictionary you need to do the following:

```
var anObject = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"key", "value"} };
```

If initializing anObject with multiple items then it would be:

```
var anObject = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            { "key1", "val1" },
            { "key2", "val2" } 
        };
```

Hope that helps!